# Use aggregate function without the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

This has been asked before, but I have not found a case quite like mine. This should be simple, if possible.

These are my tables:

```
CARS
ID | COLOR | TYPE
1  | 'Red' | 'Coupe'
2  | 'Blue'| 'Type1'
3  | 'Red' | 'Type2'
...

CAR_PARTS
ID | CAR_ID | PRICERED | PRICEBLUE
1  | 1      | 100      | 200
2  | 1      | 200      | 300
3  | 2      | 400      | 200
4  | 3      | 200      | 500
5  | 2      | 100      | 900
...
```

`CAR_PARTS.CAR_ID` is a foreign key column tied to the `ID` column of the `CARS` table, as you may have presumed. There must be a way to have a `SELECT` statement return a list of `CARS` with a `TOTAL_PRICE` column, where all `PRICERED` columns would be added where `CARS.ID = CAR_PARTS.CAR_ID` is true and `CARS.COLOR='Red'` and all 'PRICEBLUE' columns would be added where `CARS.ID = CAR_PARTS.CAR_ID` is true and `'CARS.COLOR='Blue'` is true.

Something like this:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.COLOR, C.TYPE,
SUM(CASE WHEN C.COLOR='Red' THEN P.PRICERED
         WHEN C.COLOR='Blue' THEN P.PRICEBLUE END) AS TOTAL
FROM CARS C
JOIN CAR_PARTS P ON C.ID = P.CAR_ID
```

or, as I tried, based on similar cases:

```
SELECT C.ID, C.COLOR, C.TYPE, P.TOTAL
FROM CARS C
  JOIN ( SELECT CAR_ID,
           SUM (CASE WHEN C.COLOR='Red' THEN PRICERED
             WHEN C.COLOR='Blue' THEN PRICEBLUE END) AS TOTAL
         FROM CAR_PARTS
         GROUP BY CAR_ID ) P ON C.ID = P.CAR_ID
```

Neither of these work, obviously. I understand why they don't work. The first is ambiguous to the `SQL` and the other doesn't know what `'C'` is yet. But, I wouldn't be writing a question here, if I wasn't hoping for a solution. So, I want this without the `GROUP BY` clause in the main `SELECT` statement, it is okay, although not perfect, if there is a `GROUP BY` clause within the `JOIN` clause. Thanks :).

**Edit: Desired output format**

```
ID | COLOR | TYPE   | TOTAL
1  | 'Red' | 'Coupe'| 300
2  | 'Blue'| 'Type1'| 1100
3  | 'Red' | 'Type2'| 200
```

So, `TOTAL` is 300 because the `COLOR` is `'Red'`, 1100 for the `CAR_ID=2` and `COLOR='Blue'`, 200 for `CAR_ID=3` and `COLOR='Red'`.

**Edit 2: TL;DR (or did not understand)**

Well, the output should be of the whole `CARS` table but with added `TOTAL` column which is calculated based on the other, `CAR_PARTS`, table. `SQL` should check the `CAR_ID` of the car and sum all the `PRICE` values depending on the `COLOR` of the car. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: show your desired output please.

Comment: Don't really understand what your question actually is here, like @Tanner said, expected output would really help. To answer the statement made as the questions subject though: You can't use an aggregate function in SQL Server without a `GROUP BY` in you are also including non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Hint: `SELECT ID, CAR_ID, 'Red' AS Color, PRICERED AS Price UNION ALL SELECT ID, CAR_ID, 'Blue', PRICEBLUE`. (Or `UNPIVOT`. Or even better, normalize your data properly.)

Comment: Desired output added. Sorry for not-so-understandable question.

Comment: Can you add more sample data?

Comment: Do you have any say over the schema design of `CAR_PARTS`? Because this would be a lot easier if it was [long-form](https://sejdemyr.github.io/r-tutorials/basics/wide-and-long/) i.e. you replace `PRICERED` and `PRICEBLUE` with `COLOUR` and `PRICE`. It would also mean you could add new colours without having to change your query.

Comment: This is only as example, my table names and properties are written in my language and are some finances-based terms so it was not appropriate here.

Comment: So, could you, therefore, also have a car with a value of `'GREEN'` for `[Color]`, and thus, your `[CAR_PARTS]` table will also have a column `[PRICEGREEN]`? If so, the problem is going to be your table design; and the only way to get this working properly is change it, or use Dynamic SQL.

Comment: Yes, @Larnu, but I am not in the position of altering the table.

Comment: Looks like it's going to need Dynamic SQL then, if you want to work out of the box. Give me a bit.

Comment: Okay, but bare in mind that `COLOR` is actually of `int` type, this was just the first thing I could think of as an example.

Comment: And, instead of the other 'when-then' within the `SQL` `CASE`, it can just be `ELSE`.

Comment: what is wrong with the provide answer?

Comment: I need the answer without the `GROUP BY` clause, and I have yet to try the other one.

Comment: @Adder What do you mean without `GROUP BY`? As I stated in my initial comment: *You can't use an aggregate function in SQL Server without a `GROUP BY` in you are also including non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.* If you want to return `C.Color` and the `SUM` of some other columns, you **must** use (as a minimum) `GROUP BY C.Color`. You can't avoid that; as omitting it would be invalid Syntax.

Comment: @Larnu Look at my second example, there is only one `GROUP BY`, and is within the `JOIN` clause. Something like that would work for me. It is a table with 50+ columns, how much of a performance blow would it be to have 50+ `GROUP BY` clauses?

Comment: @Adder That second answer has a `GROUP BY` as well, in the subquery. If you want to completely omit a `GROUP BY` you'd have to use a subquery for every colour; which would perform terribly if you're suggesting you have 50 colours.

Comment: No, not 50 colors, 50 other columns within `CAR` table. And yes, I wrote I am okay with having a `GROUP BY` within the subquery.

Comment: @Larnu You can do `MAX()` without `GROUP BY`.   `SELECT MAX(field) FROM Table` Is a valid query.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza " **if you are also including non-aggregated columns.** " Have a look at my answer, and you'll see a fine example of a `SUM` without a `GROUP BY` which i posted over an hour ago. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as I said in the comments, the problem here in your table design. You shouldn't be designing tables like this; it doesn't follow Normal form, and you end up with problems like you're having here.

Firstly, let's looks at this with just the 2 colours we have:

```
CREATE TABLE Car (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                  Colour varchar(10),
                  [Type] varchar(10));
GO

CREATE TABLE CarPart (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                      CarID int,
                      PriceRed int,
                      PriceBlue int);

INSERT INTO Car (Colour, [Type])
VALUES ('Red','Coupe'),
       ('Blue','Type1'),
       ('Blue','Type2');

INSERT INTO CarPart (CarId, PriceRed, PriceBlue)
VALUES (1, 100, 200),
       (1, 200, 300),
       (2, 400, 200),
       (3, 200, 500),
       (2, 100, 900);
```

Your desired result can easily be achieved using the following:

```
SELECT C.ID,
       C.Colour,
       C.[Type],
       SUM(CASE C.Colour WHEN 'Red' THEN CP.PriceRed
                         WHEN 'Blue' THEN CP.PriceBlue END) AS Total
FROM Car C
     JOIN CarPart CP ON C.ID = CP.CarID
GROUP BY C.ID,
         C.Colour,
         C.[Type];
```

But, as you said, there might be more than 2 colours, and if there are this means another column in the table `CarPart`. So, let's do that:

```
ALTER TABLE CarPart ADD PriceGreen int;
GO

INSERT INTO Car (Colour, [Type])
VALUES ('Green','Coupe');

INSERT INTO CarPart (CarId, PriceRed, PriceBlue, PriceGreen)
VALUES (4, 500, 200, 100),
       (4, 300, 700, 250);
```

OK, but now our prior query won't work. So, we have to update the query for Green as well:

```
SELECT C.ID,
       C.Colour,
       C.[Type],
       SUM(CASE C.Colour WHEN 'Red' THEN CP.PriceRed
                         WHEN 'Blue' THEN CP.PriceBlue
                         WHEN 'Green' THEN CP.PriceGreen END) AS Total
FROM Car C
     JOIN CarPart CP ON C.ID = CP.CarID
GROUP BY C.ID,
         C.Colour,
         C.[Type];
```

Not great really, is it? You see the problem already. Now let's add another column, for black, just to start making thing even more difficult:

```
ALTER TABLE CarPart ADD PriceBlack int;
GO

INSERT INTO Car (Colour, [Type])
VALUES ('Black','Hatchback');

INSERT INTO CarPart (CarId, PriceRed, PriceBlue, PriceGreen, PriceBlack)
VALUES (5, 300, 300, 200, 200),
       (5, 500, 300, 300, 400);
```

This is getting a real problem now. How many more colours might we have? Yellow, Orange, SkyBlue, Green, Magenta? How about Gold, White, Silver? I can keep listing... Either way, this set up is going badly. Thus, we need to do the solution dynamically:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'
SELECT C.ID,
       C.Colour,
       C.[Type],
       SUM(CASE C.Colour ' + STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT NCHAR(10) + N'WHEN ''' + REPLACE(C.Colour,N'''',N'''''') + N''' THEN CP.' + QUOTENAME(N'Price' + C.Colour)
                                    FROM Car C
                                    FOR XML PATH(N'')),1,1,'') + N' END) AS Total
FROM Car C
     JOIN CarPart CP ON C.ID = CP.CarID
GROUP BY C.ID,
         C.Colour,
         C.[Type];';

PRINT @SQL;

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Now, that works regardless of the number of columns we add. Great!

A small proviso though, this **relies** on your table `CarPart` having the appropriate column for the colour. if you have the colour `'HotPink'` in the table `Car`, but no column `PriceHotPink` in the table `CarPart` then this'll fall over. If this is an issue, then comment with extra logic definition, and I'll see what i can do.

*Edit: It also relies on the column having (exactly) the same name. if you have the value `'Sky Blue'` in the table `Car`, but the column `PriceSkyBlue`, then this'll also cause the dynamic SQL to fail; as the Dynamic SQl will attempt to return data from the column `[PriceSky Blue]`.*

Either way though, you need to reconsider your table design. This is not a scalable solution, and it's only going to get "worse".

*Clean up:*

```
DROP TABLE CarPart;
DROP TABLE Car;
```

*EDIT2: So, without `GROUP BY` and without the extra colours that the Op has now said won't be added...*

```
SELECT C.ID,
       C.Colour,
       C.[Type],
       CASE C.Colour WHEN 'Red' THEN (SELECT SUM(PriceRed) FROM CarPart CP WHERE CP.CarID = C.ID)
                     ELSE (SELECT SUM(PRiceBlue) FROM CarPart CP WHERE CP.CarID = C.ID) END AS Total
FROM Car C;
```

*But, why you would want to do it this way is beyond me.*

Comment: Well, I have to say I appreciate your answer, but, as I said in my question, it needs to be without the `GROUP BY` clause. And, imagine a world with only two colors (red and blue), what would be the best approach in that case? `COLOR` also has a foreign key to another table, it cannot be any other than 'Red' or 'Blue'.

Comment: @Adder What do you "Without `GROUP By`. I keep repeating myself here, but: *You can't use an aggregate function in SQL Server without a `GROUP BY` if you are also including non-aggregated columns in the `SELECT` clause.* You can't not have a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You also answered, in the comments of the question, "Yes", when i asked if there could be mroe colours than Red and Blue. Is this now not the case..?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not realize at the time it was a foreign key. Yes, it is now not the case. I told you it can be of format 'If red (..) else (...)'.

Comment: @Adder Added a different answer at the bottom, which doesn't use `GROUP BY` at all... -_-

Comment: Oh, `SUM` within `CASE`. I had it other way around. And don't you think it is cleaner to have just one subquery instead of 50+ `GROUP BY`'s? But, the reason is code generating, we can easily implement your solution to our `SELECT` query generator.

Comment: Anyway, this is working great, just as I wanted it, thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

use below code

```
SELECT C.ID, C.COLOR, C.TYPE, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN C.COLOR='Red' THEN P.PRICERED 
                WHEN C.COLOR='Blue' THEN P.PRICEBLUE END) AS TOTAL 
FROM CARS C 
JOIN CAR_PARTS P 
  ON C.ID = P.CAR_ID 
group by C.ID, C.COLOR, C.TYPE
```

or use APPLY

```
       SELECT C.ID, C.COLOR, C.TYPE, t.TOTAL
    FROM CARS C
      CROSS APPLY  ( SELECT CAR_ID,
               SUM (CASE WHEN C.COLOR='Red' THEN PRICERED
                 WHEN C.COLOR='Blue' THEN PRICEBLUE END) AS TOTAL
             FROM CAR_PARTS
             GROUP BY CAR_ID  P ON C.ID = P.CAR_ID
             )t
```

Answer (score 0):

I just need to add another simpler  approach using `OVER()` and `CASE` (this would help you avoiding using additional subqueries and `GROUP BY`).

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Car.ID, 
    Car.Color, 
    Car.Type,   
    SUM(CASE WHEN Car.Color = 'Red' THEN CP.PRICERED WHEN Car.Color = 'Blue' THEN CP.PRICEBLUE END) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY Car.ID ORDER BY Car.ID ASC) AS TOTAL 
FROM #CARS Car
JOIN #CAR_PARTS CP ON Car.ID =  CP.CAR_ID
```